# I have a very strange error in my build.log file when running make -j2 error in debian 8

Tags: c++, makefile, debian

When running ./bin/gbuild ../learncoin/contrib/gitian-descriptors/deps-win32.yml in gitian-builder on debian 8 in a VM i get this error and have no idea how to fix it. If anyone can help it would be awesome. Thanks Jamie ;)

```
+ make -j2 library_build
./libtool --mode=compile i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -I. -I../dist/..  -O3  ../dist/../mutex/mut_win32.c
./libtool --mode=compile i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -I. -I../dist/..  -O3  ../dist/../btree/bt_compare.c
libtool: compile:  i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -I. -I../dist/.. -O3 ../dist/../mutex/mut_win32.c -o mut_win32.o
libtool: compile:  i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -I. -I../dist/.. -O3 ../dist/../btree/bt_compare.c -o bt_compare.o
In file included from ../dist/../mutex/mut_win32.c:9:0:
./db_config.h:600:19: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
 #define socklen_t int
                   ^
../dist/../dbinc/repmgr.h:502:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘socklen_t’
 typedef int socklen_t;
             ^
In file included from ./db_int.h:886:0,
                 from ../dist/../mutex/mut_win32.c:12:
../dist/../dbinc/repmgr.h:502:1: warning: useless type name in empty declaration [enabled by default]
 typedef int socklen_t;
 ^
In file included from ../dist/../btree/bt_compare.c:44:0:
./db_config.h:600:19: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
 #define socklen_t int
                   ^
../dist/../dbinc/repmgr.h:502:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘socklen_t’
 typedef int socklen_t;
             ^
In file included from ./db_int.h:886:0,
                 from ../dist/../btree/bt_compare.c:46:
../dist/../dbinc/repmgr.h:502:1: warning: useless type name in empty declaration [enabled by default]
 typedef int socklen_t;
 ^
make: *** [mut_win32.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [bt_compare.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Just to clarify.  Is the `-j2` significant here?  Or do you see the same errors if you just run `make library_build`?

Comment: its called make $MAKEOPTS library_build in deps-win32.yml

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is something with `make`.But You can pass `-O` option for better diagnositic to print correct make invocations running in parallel.
This option instructs make to save the output from the commands it invokes and print it all once the commands are completed.
`make -j2 -O`
Based on the output you can then check the declarations of `socklen_t` if it is `int` or `uint32_t`